# How to find the correlation between two lists when one list consists of date values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-analysis, python-datetime

I'm trying to calculate the correlation between two lists every 30 days using the *pearsonr* function from scipy.

One list consists of dates (called **dateValues**), and the other one consists of sales (called **saleNumbers**). I already extracted the dates using datetime.strptime earlier and if I print out **dateValues**, I get a range of dates with an arbitrary length.

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 10, 0, 0)...etc
```

While here is the sales list:

```
saleNumbers = [3567,2348,1234,....etc]
```

However when I do

```
pearsonr(dateValues,saleNumbers)
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

After searching endlessly, I found that one can use *datetime.date* to do arithmetic between dates.

So i did this:

```
print(datetime.date(dateValues[0]) - datetime.date(dateValues[29]))
```

And sure enough that gives me 30 days for the time difference.

So I then tried this:

pearsonr(datetime.date(dateValues[0]) - datetime.date(dateValues[29]),saleNumbers)

But I then get this error

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Any ideas on how I can move forward with this? Also I don't think *datetime.date(dateValues[0]) - datetime.date(dateValues[2])* is the correct Pythonic way to handle the dates list when finding the correlation.

PS: In this image, is an Excel spreadsheet showing what I've already done, but trying to replicate here in Python: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THUoX.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert them to numeric values first:

```
arbitrary_date = datetime(1970,1,1)
pearsonr([(d - arbitrary_date).total_seconds() for d in dateValues], saleNumbers)
```

Perason correlation is unaffected by scaling or translation in either axis  (affine transformations)

Comment: thanks, but is the dt a typo and should it be d instead? Also what does this expression mean: datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() ?

Comment: @bwrr: Number of seconds between `d` and some arbitrary timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
pearsonr(np.array(dateValues, dtype=np.datetime64).astype("int"), np.array(saleNumbers))
```

Comment: `astype(np.int64)` is probably a better bet here